# Sum two different types in same column

Tags: sql, jdbc, oracle10g

Hi I have the below as sql output.

```
TYPE SUM(UPDATE_COUNT) 
Legis 93 
Acds 43 
Updates 41 
Multibases 345
```

but i want updates to be displayed as Sum of updates and Multibases and here both Multibases and Updates belong to same column. It should be like the below.

```
Updates 386
```

the query i used for the first output is

```
SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) 
FROM Scope1 
where type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and 
      (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012') 
group by type
```

please help me how do i get the second output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN type IN 'Updates','Multibases' THEN 'Updates' ELSE type END as TYPE,
  SUM(Update_Count) 
FROM
  Scope1 
WHERE
      type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll')
  and (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012') 
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN type IN 'Updates','Multibases' THEN 'Updates' ELSE type END
```

A more scalable solution is to have another table that maps `type` to `super_type`.

```
SELECT
  map.super_type,
  SUM(Scope1.update_count)
FROM
  Scope1
INNER JOIN
  map
    ON map.type = Scope1.type
WHERE
      Scope1.type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll')
  and Scope1.RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012'
  and Scope1.RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012'
GROUP BY
  map.super_type
```

Then you can put entries such as the following in your map...

```
 type       | super_type
------------+------------
 Legis      | Legis
 Acds       | Acds
 Updates    | Updates
 Multibases | Updates
```

etc, etc

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT type, SUM(case when type in ('Updates','Multibases') then Update_Count else o end) as  Update_Count 
FROM Scope1 
where type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and 
      (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012') 
group by type
```

Comment: This will still create one row for each type; it won't merge `Updates` and `Multibases` into a single row, which is what the OP wants. Also, the `CASE` statement being inside the `SUM()` will force the `Update_Count` result to `0` for every `type` that isn't `in ('Updates','Multibases')`. *[Atleast it would if you had `ELSE 0` instead of `ELSE o`.]*

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one off then use one of the other solutions. Here's a data driven idea if you might change your groupings in future:

```
Create Table TypeBucket (
  type varchar(50) not null primary key, 
  bucket varchar(50) not null
);

Insert Into TypeBucket (type, bucket) values 
  ('Legis', 'Legis'),
  ('Acds', 'Acds'),
  ('Updates', 'Updates'),
  ('Multibases', 'Updates'),
  ('LegAll', 'LegAll'),
  ('DAIS', 'DAIS');

Select
  b.bucket,
  Sum(s.update_count)
From
  Scope1 s
    Inner Join
  TypeBucket b
    On s.type = b.Type
Where
  s.type in ('Updates', 'Multibases', 'DAIS', 'Acds', 'Legis', 'LegAll') And
  s.recvd_date >= '04/02/2012' And 
  s.recvd_date < '12/1/2012'
Group By
  b.bucket
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) 
FROM Scope1 
where type in ('DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and 
      (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012') 
group by type
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Updates' AS type, SUM(Update_Count) 
FROM Scope1 
where type in ('Updates','Multibases') and 
      (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012')
```

Will produce the following:

```
TYPE SUM(UPDATE_COUNT) 
Legis 93 
Acds 43 
Updates 386
```

---

Or you can also use a `CASE` to produce the same output:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type IN ('Updates','Multibases') THEN 'Updates' ELSE type END AS type, SUM(Update_Count) 
FROM Scope1 
where type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and 
      (RECVD_DATE >='04/02/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='11/30/2012') 
group by CASE WHEN type IN ('Updates','Multibases') THEN 'Updates' ELSE type END
```